# Tokenizing unicode using nltk

Tags: python, unicode, nltk, tokenize

I have textfiles that use utf-8 encoding that contain characters like 'ö', 'ü', etc. I would like to parse the text form these files, but I can't get the tokenizer to work properly. If I use standard nltk tokenizer:

```
f = open('C:\Python26\text.txt', 'r') # text = 'müsli pöök rääk'
text = f.read()
f.close
items = text.decode('utf8')
a = nltk.word_tokenize(items)
```

---

Output: `[u'\ufeff', u'm', u'\xfc', u'sli', u'p', u'\xf6', u'\xf6', u'k', u'r', u'\xe4', u'\xe4', u'k']`

Punkt tokenizer seems to do better:

```
f = open('C:\Python26\text.txt', 'r') # text = 'müsli pöök rääk'
text = f.read()
f.close
items = text.decode('utf8')
a = PunktWordTokenizer().tokenize(items)
```

---

output: `[u'\ufeffm\xfcsli', u'p\xf6\xf6k', u'r\xe4\xe4k']`

There is still '\ufeff' before the first token that i can't figure out (not that I can't remove it). What am I doing wrong? Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's more likely that the `\uFEFF` char is part of the content read from the file. I doubt it was inserted by the tokeniser. `\uFEFF` at the beginning of a file is a deprecated form of [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark). If it appears anywhere else, then it is treated as a [zero width non-break space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_non-breaking_space).

Was the file written by Microsoft Notepad? From [the codecs module docs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode):

> To increase the reliability with which a UTF-8 encoding can be detected, Microsoft invented a variant of UTF-8 (that Python 2.5 calls "utf-8-sig") for its Notepad program: Before any of the Unicode characters is written to the file, a UTF-8 encoded BOM (which looks like this as a byte sequence: 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf) is written.

Try reading your file using [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) instead. Note the `"utf-8-sig"` encoding which consumes the BOM.

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open('C:\Python26\text.txt', 'r', 'utf-8-sig')
text = f.read()
a = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
```

Experiment:

```
>>> open("x.txt", "r").read().decode("utf-8")
u'\ufeffm\xfcsli'
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.open("x.txt", "r", "utf-8-sig").read()
u'm\xfcsli'
>>>
```

Answer (score 13):

You should make sure that you're passing unicode strings to nltk tokenizers. I get the following identical tokenizations of your string with both tokenizers on my end:

```
import nltk
nltk.wordpunct_tokenize('müsli pöök rääk'.decode('utf8'))
# output : [u'm\xfcsli', u'p\xf6\xf6k', u'r\xe4\xe4k']

nltk.word_tokenize('müsli pöök rääk'.decode('utf8'))
# output: [u'm\xfcsli', u'p\xf6\xf6k', u'r\xe4\xe4k']
```

Answer (score 4):

the UFEE code is a "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE" character and this is not consider as a space by the `re` module, so the `PunktWordTokenizer()` which use the regex `r'\w+|[^\w\s]+'` with unicode and dotall flags recognize this character as a word. If you don't want to remove the character manually, you could use the following tokenizer:

```
nltk.RegexpTokenizer(u'\w+|[^\w\s\ufeff]+')
```