# Iterate through python list

Tags: python, list, nltk

I have UTF-8 Unicode text file as below (non-english)

[image: unicode textfile]

So I marked encoding as UTF-8 in python and imported file into python.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I have tokenized sentences by "." and got list of **sentences**.

[image: sentence list]

Now i need to compare with another unicode word list and find out whether any of those words in each sentence.

This is my code. But it shows only first match identified.

```
for sentence in sentences:
    for word in sentence.split(" "):
        if word in pronouns:
            print sentence
```

EDIT:

Finally I noticed there is invalid unicode character in source text files. 
It is described here [Tokenizing unicode using nltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228202/tokenizing-unicode-using-nltk)

Comment: There is nothing obvious in what you are showing us. Have you confirmed how many items are in sentences? Is there more than one pronoun in the haystack?

Comment: As you can see there are 6 sentences. and there are set of pronouns. Each of those sentence started with one pronoun in the list. So it suppose to show all sentences one by one.

Comment: You are probably better off just using `sentence.split()`. Some alphabets may have whitespace characters that do not match `" "`.

Comment: Also note there are three sentences starting with same pronoun.

Comment: Sorry, I am not being clear enough. You have a list named 'sentences' and you think it has 6 items in it because your eyeballs tell you there are 6 sentences in our data. But perhaps the program is not seeing things the same way your eyes are seeing things. If you try print('len(sentences) = ' + len(sentences)) what is the output? Do you actually have the 6 sentences you expect in the list? I am touching on the same issues of encoding and the like that @KarTo is, wisely, suggesting needs to be explored as a possible source of your problems.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to simulate your problem, but I get the expected result, maybe the problem is in the Encoding or in your list of pronouns.

```
pronouns = ['aa','bb','cc']

sentences = ['aa dkdje asdf aesr','bb asersada','cc ase aser sa sa c ','aa saef sf se s', 'aa','bb']

for sentence in sentences:
    for word in sentence.split(" "):
        if word in pronouns:
            print (sentence)
```

The output of the code was:

```
aa dkdje asdf aesr
bb asersada
cc ase aser sa sa c 
aa saef sf se s
aa
bb
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks. But for me it didn't work. May be Unicode must be handled some other way.